# Page id asp.net security

Tags: asp.net, security

i have u question about security ins aps.net

i have a page http://localhost:1522/Public/ViewPost.aspx?PostID=40

i want to disable function when user in addresbar deletes id 40 like this

http://localhost:1522/Public/ViewPost.aspx?PostID=

it redirects to page viewpost and it is a problem i want to disabel this or redirect

Comment: Your question is unclear, please try to be more specific. Add the code of your page maybe.

Answer (score 3):

if(Request.QueryString["PostID"]==null)
{
  // your logic here

}

Answer (score 2):

in the page load, you can check for the `PostID` value and if it is empty you can redirect the page.

Answer (score 0):

There's more to what you need to know here than just checking if it's blank ( which the others have already posted simply a check if your item == null) 
What if a user enters in an Id they don't have access to? postId=120 for example belongs to another user. You need to check if the current user also has access to the specified record.
Since we don't know your app or schema we can't give specifics but keep in mind how you need to validate that PostId actually is valid for the current user